# pthread_exit(NULL) segfaults

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

I have a project using pthreads; there's the main thread and a sub-thread and a pipe between them. It's all working fine, except *sometimes* it doesn't work. The sub thread runs a command interpreter and an ncurses-based GUI shuttles (some) input over the pipe to it.

I create the thread normally (thread is a pthread_t file-scope variable, interp_start is the function)

```
if (pthread_create(&thread, NULL, interp_start, NULL)) { perror("couldn't create thread"); return; }
```

Then, if the interpreter thread receives an "exit" command from the user, it calls interp_exit

```
fclose(output);
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

The main thread has a select() that examines, among other things, output's FD and calls a function that read()s from the FD:

```
int num=read(interp_output[0], &ch, 1);
if (num==0) shell_done();
if (num==-1) perror("read");
```

The intended behavior, which often works, is to close the FILE* in the thread, which makes the select() report ready, which makes the read() happen, which returns 0, which calls shell_done(). This does, after some simple and unrelated cleanup:

```
//fprintf(stderr, "joining thread\n");
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
//fprintf(stderr, "joined\n");
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

All of this *sometimes* segfaults. Usually it's fine. If I uncomment those two printfs, if it fails I get neither (it segfaults in pthread_exit) or just the first (it segfaults in pthread_join).

I'm not messing with 'thread' at any other point, and I'm only dealing with null pointers. What's the deal? I'd be looking elsewhere except I'm consistently having problems at one of those two lines - once even at restore_sem_to_pool. I think it has to be the way I'm killing the thread, but I'm doing just about the simplest thing possible.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have a mimsatch between # of arguments and the format string in one of the (s)(f)printf family of calls?

Comment: Where does `gdb` say that the segfault happens?

Comment: @jim - I don't think so. Where would you like me to look - in the thread, in the main program, or in any shared variables?

Comment: @caf - A few times it's been at the join, a few times it was at the pthread_exit, and a few times it's been in restore_sem_to_pool (called by pt_join per the backtrace). Oh! just now got one in _pthread_tsd_cleanup() - from pthread_exit()

Comment: Further clarification - I've seen an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at address 0x0 (dereferencing a null pointer), I've seen EXC_BAD_ACCESS at 0xffff....c which sounds like a small negative number to me, and so on. All of these are functions that I'm passing NULL to, but are written to expect it.

Comment: Sounds like memory corruption..

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing more code.  Can you reduce this to a smaller, complete example?  My gut says that you've got some memory corruption going on.  Do you still see problems if you pad the definition of `thread` with big buffers on both sides?

Comment: @Robert: Have you done a backtrace of *every* thread? Remember that the thread that actually segfaults will cause every other thread to be killed, too (at a fairly random place).  I think you're looking at the wrong backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's a combination of all of these, but the problem went away. It only happened when I typed 'quit' too soon after the program started, but I don't have time to properly debug this now and the assignment is due already anyway. @John - I actually was setting up valgrind for just this purpose. **[EDIT]** I ran it earlier and it didn't help me with this problem, but I definitely found some memory I wasn't freeing **[/EDIT]** Everybody else - I think you're right, it's probably some sort of memory corruption. @caf - I forgot to check other thread... but I was seeing the problem in both threads. GDB was pointing me at the one that was actually segfaulting. **[EDIT]** I checked the other threads and it was either waiting on the pt_join (if the segfault was with the pt_exit) or somewhere just before the pt_exit (if the segfault was in the pt_join) **[/EDIT]**

Votes to all, but I don't think it's fair to accept an answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `valgrind` (specifically the "memcheck" part).  It can quickly help you to pinpoint invalid memory accesses at runtime, sometimes even including runs of your program that do not crash.